# Members default properties are not available in code

Tags: umbraco

Im using `UmbracoMembersUserManager.FindByEmailAsync()` to get the user and then `UmbracoApplicationMember.MemberProperties` to get the properties.

All of my custom properties are there, but Umbraco (locked) properties don't appear. eg: "umbracoMemberApproved" is not retrieved.

I have both "Show on member profile" and "Member can edit" activated for this property, but still it is not on the "MemberProperties" list.

What might be the issue? What can I check more?

Comment: Which Umbraco version is this? Please add more details.

Comment: It was 8.12. I was able to get a workaround. Made another call, but using IMemberService.GetById(user.Id). This time all the properties were available. Yes 2 calls is not very efficient, but gets the job done

Comment: Thanks, Pedro for the reply. It could be good if you share your solution as a new answer and mark it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from your answer.